# Streaming live video onto uiWebView issue

Tags: objective-c, ipad, video-streaming

I am using the Wowza streaming engine to stream a live video stream to *many* iPads (up to 400).

The stream address looks like "http://myserver:1935/live/mystream/playlist.m3u8".

The iPads all start streaming the live video, but after some varying period of time, most of the iPads will stop streaming and just show the last image as if the video stopped streaming at a certain point. This could happen 30 seconds in or 3 hours in or NEVER. I have 3 iPads in my test case of 40 that are still streaming after 14 hours.

The logs yield nothing of consequence related to this.  I do not lose my wifi signal.  The iPads still respond to other TCP/IP commands from my server to them.

I am using a UIWebView with the command:

```
[_theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:szURL]]];
```

Is there any way I can track whether or not data is still streaming to the UIWebView?

If not, is there another way to stream this video within my app?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone ever sees this question, the answer was not in the iPad code, but in the Wowza configuration. I had changed chunks and chunk sizes to try and minimize the delay, and that caused the video to freeze when the buffers ran out and the streaming engine could not refill them fast enough.